# How to use squeeze and reset_index in Dask dataframe?

Tags: pandas, group-by, dask, dask-dataframe

[image: 1]

I want to do this in Dask dataframe..
Originally, in Pandas dataframe, I tried squeeze and reset_index as you can see below:

```
df.groupby(['A', 'B']).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(range(x['C'].squeeze()))).reset_index()
df.groupby(['A', 'B']).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(range(x['C'].squeeze()))).reset_index()[['A', 'B']]
```

But the data I need to transform is too large to compute, so I need to use Dask to make it work faster.
And the code above does not work in the same way in Dask dataframe when I simply replaced pd to dd (dask.dataframe).

How can I do the same work using Dask?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['Male', 'Female'],
    'Age': [29, 43],
    'Pet': ['Cat', 'Dog'],
    'Allergie': ['negative', 'positive'],
    'Amount': [2, 4]
})

ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)

def apply_func(partition):
    if partition.empty:
        return pd.DataFrame(columns=partition.columns)
    result = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(partition.iloc[0, :-1]).transpose()] * partition['Amount'].squeeze())
    return result

meta = pd.DataFrame({'Name': pd.Series([], dtype='str'),
                     'Age': pd.Series([], dtype='int64'),
                     'Pet': pd.Series([], dtype='str'),
                     'Allergie': pd.Series([], dtype='str')})

result = ddf.map_partitions(apply_func, meta=meta).reset_index(drop=True)
```

and

```
result.compute()
```

returns

```
     Name Age  Pet  Allergie
0    Male  29  Cat  negative
1    Male  29  Cat  negative
0  Female  43  Dog  positive
1  Female  43  Dog  positive
2  Female  43  Dog  positive
3  Female  43  Dog  positive
```